# WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0 - LDAP & Publisher API Token Issue

Tags: oauth, ldap, wso2-api-manager, wso2

I've configured WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0 to have internal user store as primary, and LDAP as the secondary user store. I can login to Carbon, Publisher and Store UIs with LDAP users. My aim is to allow LDAP users to consume Publisher REST APIs and the steps I've followed are below;

1. Create Service Provider

   ```
   curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{    "clientName": "rest_api_publisher",    "tokenScope": "Production",    "owner": "admin",    "grantType": "password refresh_token",    "saasApp": true }' "http://localhost:9763/client-registration/v0.10/register"
   ```

   Response

   ```
           {
             "jsonString": "{\"username\":\"admin\",\"redirect_uris\":null,\"client_name\":\"admin_rest_api_publisher\",\"grant_types\":\"urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml2-bearer iwa:ntlm refresh_token client_credentials password\"}",
             "appOwner": null,
             "clientName": null,
             "callBackURL": null,
             "isSaasApplication": true,
             "clientId": "N2GP9igHPkEcotmyE6ccyPLBeh0a",
             "clientSecret": "qHO0ZFsaGDGGEaHO_4PXgKOXVWYa"
           }
   ```
2. Get Access Token for admin user

   ```
   curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic TjJHUDlpZ0hQa0Vjb3RteUU2Y2N5UExCZWgwYTpxSE8wWkZzYUdER0dFYUhPXzRQWGdLT1hWV1lh" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" "https://localhost:8243/token?grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin&scope=apim:api_view%20apim:api_publish%20apim:api_create"
   ```

   Response

   ```
           {
             "scope": "apim:api_create apim:api_publish apim:api_view",
             "token_type": "Bearer",
             "expires_in": 3600,
             "refresh_token": "787b34a2-55eb-3baa-b83a-7041959781ce",
             "access_token": "2b7ad48c-67d8-3ebc-acd8-1d02aca85fdd"
           }
   ```

As you can see in this case, the scope contains all the scopes that I've requested. With this token I can query and add new APIs and publish them. The issue I'm having is that when I do the same with the LDAP user, the scope is default.

(P.S.: My secondary domain name is mzaferyahsi.com)

3. Get Access Token for ldap user

   ```
   curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic TjJHUDlpZ0hQa0Vjb3RteUU2Y2N5UExCZWgwYTpxSE8wWkZzYUdER0dFYUhPXzRQWGdLT1hWV1lh" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" "https://localhost:8243/token?grant_type=password&username=mzaferyahsi.com/<<username>>&password=<<password>>&scope=apim:api_view%20apim:api_publish%20apim:api_create"
   ```

   Response

   ```
           {
             "scope": "default",
             "token_type": "Bearer",
             "expires_in": 3600,
             "refresh_token": "2a519b92-2fe8-3b85-8da8-6ea8b2eceb6e",
             "access_token": "874aac4f-c441-3927-bd1b-cce859e58988"
           }
   ```

Has anybody faced this problem? Any solutions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set required role-scope mapping in `tenant-conf.json file`. The user should also have required role. The document is [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/apidocs/publisher/#configuring-rest-api).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!